# UnityException: You are not allowed to call this function when declaring a variable

Tags: unity-game-engine, runtime-error

I am trying to instantiate a GameObject and keep a reference to it but for some reason the above error appears every time it is instantiated even though the instantiation still goes through. The line of code it points me to is this: `GameObject next = Instantiate(prefab);` Like I said, the instantiation still works correctly, but in the interest of stability, I would like to get rid of this error. What does Unity want from me?

Comment: Are you using c# or Javascript?

Comment: note too that ***you should not use 'next' as a variable name*** in c#

Comment: WTF dude you need to TICK AN ANSWER!

Comment: @JoeBlow Sorry, I'm nu here. Done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're all wrong. **Roughly speaking**, Instantiate returns

## *WHAT YOU PASS IN.*

if you have this ...

```
   public GameObject modelDinosaur;
```

you can indeed have this

```
   GameObject nu = Instantiate(modelDinosaur);
```

No need to cast.  (It's totally OK to cast if you want to.)

Yes, for a prefab, do exactly what everyone tells you above

```
  GameObject nu = (GameObject)Instantiate(yourPrefab);
```

BTW it is idiomatic to use "nu" (like "new") as the temporary variable. ("new" is a keyword of course, you can't use that.)

Most commonly you then do these things ..

```
   GameObject nu = Instantiate(modelDinosaur);
   YourDinoScript nuD = nu.GetComponent<YourDinoScript>();
   yourDinoList.Add(nuD);
   nu.name = "dynamic " + counter;
   nuT = nu.transform;
   nuT = blah blah
   nuT = your holder
   nuT = logic position
   etc etc
```

PS: regarding Unity's doco, you might as well read the ravings of a drunk chatbot. Forget it.

Comment: hi, Why are you talking about `nu`?

Comment: I know that, it is reserved word. How does this have to do with that question asked by @redstonerusty ?

Comment: Good answer Joe. I know this is off but I want to know why you should not use the 'next' as a variable name in c#. You made this comment under the question and I don't get it.....

Comment: I googled "next C# keyword" before asking this question. Not sure if it is. I tried in my editor and it was not highlighted... continue is

Answer (score 2):

`Instantiate()` return an `Object`, You need to cast it to `GameObject` Explicitly.

**Try this:**

```
GameObject next = (GameObject)Instantiate(prefab);
```

**More information:**

`Instantiate()` signature: `public static Object Instantiate(Object original)`

This clearly shows that the return type is `Object` and not `Gameobject`

**Reference**

Please refer to [this](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) for more details

Comment: No, Instantiate returns a GameObject. Otherwise it wouldn't even compile.

Comment: Please check here : http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html

Comment: @RedstoneRusty .. you're totally wrong here dude!  :)

Answer (score 2):

The Unity `Instantiate` method has a return type of `Object`.  You need to instantiate your prefab as a `GameObject` if you want to store it in a `GameObject` variable.

Assuming you are using C#, you can instantiate a GameObject and store it in a variable like so:

```
GameObject myGameObject = Instantiate(prefab) as GameObject;
```

Comment: No, Instantiate returns a GameObject. Otherwise it wouldn't even compile.

Comment: Instantiate has a return type of Object, not GameObject http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html